# Is set of even integers an integral domain?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Set of even integers forms a commutative ring with no zero divisors.
But it does not have unity.
So is it an integral domain? 
Few books say that integral domain should possess unity and some books do not consider it as a necessary condition.

Comment: that's going to be a case-by-case basis. I'm a professional who doesn't demand my rings have a 1, others do. It's not standardized.

Comment: I would say no, but then again, that is just a matter of taste and what you tend to use rings for.

Comment: I would also say no.  All the books I'm fond of require $1 \in R$.  :P

Comment: Whether a ring must have unity took several years of [Wikipedia discussion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Ring_(mathematics)/Archive_1) with no conclusion except that older textbooks were less likely to require it. I like *rng* - a ring without $i$.

Comment: It is a matter of convention. Nowadays by far the most common convention is that an integral domain is a ring with $1$.